DNS resolution in NAT gateway blocked by ufw
I have a LAN (172.16.0.0/24) and 2 servers:

"Bastion" (172.16.0.3), which has a public IP and can reach internet
"Redis" (172.16.0.4), which doesn't have a public IP and can't reach internet

The LAN has a route with destination 0.0.0.0/0 and gateway 172.16.0.3 (the "Bastion" server).
I have executed the following commands in "Bastion":
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '172.16.0.0/24' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ufw allow in from 172.16.0.0/24 to any proto tcp
ufw allow in from 172.16.0.0/24 to any proto udp
ufw allow out to 172.16.0.0/24 proto tcp
ufw allow out to 172.16.0.0/24 proto udp

And this is what I have executed in "Redis":
ip route add default via 172.16.0.1
echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
resolvconf -u

In theory, this should make it possible for "Redis" to reach internet by using "Bastion" as a gateway. And surely if I execute ping 1.2.3.4 in "Redis" I do get responses. But if I execute ping google.com in "Redis" the DNS resolution fails.
DNS resolution in "Redis" starts working after disabling ufw in "Bastion", which makes me believe that this is the root of the problem.
This is the ufw status of "Bastion":
root@Bastion:/home/admin# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
19999/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW       172.16.0.0/24/tcp
Anywhere                   ALLOW       172.16.0.0/24/udp
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
19999/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

172.16.0.0/24/tcp          ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
172.16.0.0/24/udp          ALLOW OUT   Anywhere

And this is the journalctl -f of "Bastion" while running ping google.com in "Redis":
May 11 17:26:31 Bastion kernel: [UFW AUDIT] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=96:00:03:4b:d7:01:d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3:08:00 SRC=170.253.1.40 DST=159.69.249.223 LEN=88 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=60530 DPT=22 WINDOW=2048 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
May 11 17:27:04 Bastion kernel: [UFW AUDIT] IN=enp7s0 OUT=eth0 MAC=86:00:00:89:fb:13:d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3:08:00 SRC=172.16.0.4 DST=1.1.1.1 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=57845 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=50244 DPT=53 LEN=35
May 11 17:27:04 Bastion kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp7s0 OUT=eth0 MAC=86:00:00:89:fb:13:d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3:08:00 SRC=172.16.0.4 DST=1.1.1.1 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=57845 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=50244 DPT=53 LEN=35
May 11 17:27:04 Bastion kernel: [UFW AUDIT] IN=enp7s0 OUT=eth0 MAC=86:00:00:89:fb:13:d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3:08:00 SRC=172.16.0.4 DST=1.1.1.1 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=57846 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=50244 DPT=53 LEN=35
May 11 17:27:04 Bastion kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp7s0 OUT=eth0 MAC=86:00:00:89:fb:13:d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3:08:00 SRC=172.16.0.4 DST=1.1.1.1 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=57846 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=50244 DPT=53 LEN=35
May 11 17:27:09 Bastion kernel: [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=enp7s0 SRC=172.16.0.3 DST=172.16.0.4 LEN=88 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=36484 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40626 DPT=22 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
May 11 17:27:09 Bastion kernel: [UFW AUDIT] IN=enp7s0 OUT=eth0 MAC=86:00:00:89:fb:13:d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3:08:00 SRC=172.16.0.4 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=39917 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60005 DPT=53 LEN=35
May 11 17:27:09 Bastion kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp7s0 OUT=eth0 MAC=86:00:00:89:fb:13:d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3:08:00 SRC=172.16.0.4 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=39917 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60005 DPT=53 LEN=35
May 11 17:27:09 Bastion kernel: [UFW AUDIT] IN=enp7s0 OUT=eth0 MAC=86:00:00:89:fb:13:d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3:08:00 SRC=172.16.0.4 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=39918 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60005 DPT=53 LEN=35
May 11 17:27:09 Bastion kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp7s0 OUT=eth0 MAC=86:00:00:89:fb:13:d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3:08:00 SRC=172.16.0.4 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=39918 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60005 DPT=53 LEN=35

And this is the iptables -L in "Bastion":
root@Bastion:/home/admin# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warn prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warn prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warn prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             mdns.mcast.net       udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warn prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warn prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warn prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warn prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID LOG level warn prefix "[UFW AUDIT INVALID] "
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warn prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh /* 'dapp_OpenSSH' */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:19999
ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.16.0.0/24        anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  172.16.0.0/24        anywhere

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warn prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/24
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/24
root@Bastion:/home/admin#

Why is ufw in "Bastion" dropping the (DNS) traffic from "Redis"?

It turns out I have to allow traffic routing in ufw, like this:
ufw route allow in on enp7s0 out on eth0

These commands are not required:
ufw allow in from 172.16.0.0/24 to any proto tcp
ufw allow in from 172.16.0.0/24 to any proto udp
ufw allow out to 172.16.0.0/24 proto tcp
ufw allow out to 172.16.0.0/24 proto udp

